# PF_RING 7.9.0 issue with deb package creation

Tags: perl, debian, deb, pf-ring

I am trying to create deb packages for my work and have run into the following trouble.
[image: Screen shot of deb package building]

The version of dkms being used as shown in the screen shot is 2.2.1.0. I have tried it out even with dkms 2.8.3 but I get the same error.

I am unsure what to do next or try next as I cannot understand.A little guidance is requested.

the exact issue that is being shown is the following. There is a Perl module named `Dh_Lib.pm` with a subroutine `should_use_root()` as shown below the error and the issue has been marked there.

```
Building binary package...dpkg-buildpackage: warning: using a gain-root-command while being root
 dpkg-source --before-build .
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
Initialization of state variables in list context currently forbidden at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm line 2021, near ");"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm line 2743.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/dh_testdir line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/dh_testdir line 11.
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:25: clean] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean subprocess returned exit status 2
(bad exit status: 2)
Error! There was a problem creating your deb.
make: *** [Makefile.dkms:28: deb] Error 7
root@VEHERE:/home/vehere/Release/probe/deps/PF_RING-7.9.0/kernel#



# Return true if we should use root.
# - Takes an optional keyword; if passed, this will return true if the keyword is listed in R^3 (Rules-Requires-Root)
# - If the optional keyword is omitted or not present in R^3 and R^3 is not 'binary-targets', then returns false
# - Returns true otherwise (i.e. keyword is in R^3 or R^3 is 'binary-targets')

sub should_use_root {
        my ($keyword) = @_;
        my $rrr_env = $ENV{'DEB_RULES_REQUIRES_ROOT'} // 'binary-targets';
        $rrr_env =~ s/^\s++//;
        $rrr_env =~ s/\s++$//;
        return 0 if $rrr_env eq 'no';
        return 1 if $rrr_env eq 'binary-targets';
        return 0 if not defined($keyword);

        state %rrr = map { $_ => 1 } split(' ', $rrr_env);   << ---- issues
        return 1 if exists($rrr{$keyword});
        return 0;
}
```

The version of perl being used is 5.24.1

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: *"The version of perl being used is 5.24.1*" I think you need perl version 5.28 or greater to initialize a hash as a state variable, see [perl5280delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5280delta#Initialisation-of-aggregate-state-variables)